# How to remove/hide duplicate/matching file name from array?

Tags: php

I am trying to remove or hide match file names from array and i also removed file extension but how to hide/remove duplicate file name if match?

If output `'demo1','demo1','demo2',` then i want to do like this `'demo1','demo2',`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) function, which does exactly that: it removes duplicates.

```
<?php 
$images = array();
foreach (glob('{*.jpg,*.png}', GLOB_BRACE) as $key=>$image) {
    $images[] = substr($image, 0, -4);
}
$images = array_unique($images);
foreach ($images as $key=>$image) {
    if ($key == 0)
    { echo "'".substr($image, 0, -4)."'"; }
    else
    { echo ",'".substr($image, 0, -4)."'"; }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you but you forgot to change `foreach ($files` to `foreach ($images`

Comment: @userknowmore Ah yes, sorry about that.